# Symfony 4 set Twig template path in controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I searched everywhere but unfortunately without result. The case is as following:
I'm using a general Symfony 4 codebase with basic TWIG template files. Next to that i have multiple domains who refer to the codebase, because of that reason I want to set the path to my TWIG files in the controller from my codebase:
`return $this->render("path/to/domain/and/twig/temp", "domain variables");`

This is not working and I can't find how to change my TWIG path withing my controller. Can somebody help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue in the meantime?

Answer (score 2):

Symfony uses **app/Resources/views/** directory for templates. If you want to change you can configure it in ***config.yml*** as below.

```
twig:
    # ...
    paths: ["%kernel.project_dir%/templates"]
```

Comment: Found that but I want to use that as original/fallback and also use a different path for each seperate domain (example: /var/www/codebase/templates for the codebase and /var/www/domain/templates for domains)